# Как отслеживать загруженность канала по портам?

Tags: ip, сервер, порты

Как на удаленном сервере отслеживать в реальном времени загруженность канала по портам и все IP адреса которые подключены к серверу?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "по портам"?Для чего это вам нужно? Это может быть трудоемко для сервера.

Comment: Необходимо это для того что бы видеть идут ли попытки брутфорса ssh(22), либо просто флуда на канал. То что трудоемким я знаю, и все же можно ли подобное организовать?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь iptables, если они установлены:    iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -m limit --limit 3/second -j ACCEPT    iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH"Все, что чаще 3 запросов в секунду, заносится в лог.Можно усложнить правила. Можно добавить правило блокировки и т.п.

Comment: а не мог бы подсказать с правилом блокировки?

Comment: Оно будет такое-же как правило логирования. Должно следовать после правила с лимитом. Главное не переусердствовать.    iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j DROP[Здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables) есть неплохой мануал.Так же существуют программные продукты называемые "Система обнаружения вторжений", например [Snort](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort), но тоже систему будет грузить.

Comment: Пример: после 3 не удачных попыток IP  блокируется на 3 мин.> # SSH Brut Force - $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i ${ext-if} --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource - $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i ${ext-if} --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 180 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH_brute_force " - $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i ${ext-if} -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 180 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j DROP - $iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите утилиту iftop.

Брутфорс отслеживается по логу. Порт 22 можно сменить в файле конфигурации ssh (после чего надо перезапустить sshd).

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить fail2ban замечательная утилита Её можно  прикрутить к любому сервису ,принцип работы очень простой она парсит лог файлы на наличие неудачной авторизации Настраивается через регэкспы ..... может отсылать отчёты на почту .... вообщем посмотрите в эту сторону кстати работает она в связке с iptables